# Cluster to Cluster replication in gridDB

Tags: database, griddb

is there any way to setup cluster to cluster replication for gridDB in case one cluster goes down? I really want to have  high availability environment in case my cluster in one environment goes down, thank you.

I read documentations online but cannot find a clear way to do this or cannot find an efficent way to do it.